How do i move smooth the Content Rect Transform from it's current position to the right and then bring it back from the left and keep scrolling?
The project is in 2d.

i want to move the content smoothly to the right and when the content is moving "out" from the inside to bring it back from the left side and make keep it scrolling that way nonstop.
I tried to attach to the content this script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingContent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform content;       // Reference to the Content RectTransform
    public float scrollSpeed = 5f;      // Speed at which the content scrolls
    private List<RectTransform> items;  // List to keep track of all the child items

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize the list and populate it with the items
        items = new List<RectTransform>();
        for (int i = 0; i < content.childCount; i++)
        {
            items.Add(content.GetChild(i).GetComponent<RectTransform>());
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Move each item to the right
        foreach (RectTransform item in items)
        {
            item.anchoredPosition += Vector2.right * scrollSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Check if the first item has moved past the viewable area
        if (items[0].anchoredPosition.x > GetRightEdgeX(content))
        {
            // Calculate the width of the first item
            float itemWidth = items[0].sizeDelta.x;

            // Move the first item to the end of the list
            RectTransform firstItem = items[0];
            items.RemoveAt(0);
            items.Add(firstItem);

            // Place it on the left side of the last item
            RectTransform lastItem = items[items.Count - 2];
            firstItem.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(lastItem.anchoredPosition.x - itemWidth, lastItem.anchoredPosition.y);
        }
    }

    // Utility function to get the right edge X position of the RectTransform
    private float GetRightEdgeX(RectTransform rt)
    {
        return rt.anchoredPosition.x + rt.rect.width;
    }
}

but this makes the content moving just a bit to the right and then jump back to its original start position and so on over and over again moving a bit and jump back over.
i want it to move like a conveyor belt.

Seems to work for me ... the only "issue" is maybe that the anchored position of your images is pivoted to the center (default) so the jump already happens when it is only half over the edge of the content ... you might rather check in which direction you are "scrolling" and use e.g. the right edge of your images instead of the center so basically if(GetLeftEdge(item[0]) > GetRightEdge(content))
